# Chrome Apps Cordova webview shows a blank page

Tags: cordova, webview, google-chrome-app

It's quite a weird situation which I am in. I've recently found out about the Chrome Apps ability, you can port them automatically to iOs, Android and Windows. But I do have a problem, I've been writing the application in Javascript as a base and tested it with the Chrome Editor, worked fine in the windows mode.

I've been struggling on porting it to android and when it finally worked, my webview was empty. After 2 hours of trying, googling and messing around I decided to give up and just take a sample and work from there. But even the samples aren't giving me the webview.

The webview stays empty, all I can see is that I keep getting 4 errors which are not related to the script itself ( sychronous XMLHttpRequest, failed to load a css and a lost .html file from a chrome-extension ).

Debugging the app; text shows up, webview stays blank.
Anyone ever had the same problem?

### [image: The gray box is the webview tag]

The entire file contains the following code;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WebView sample</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 
 <webview id="wv2" style="width:250px; height:200px;" src="http://google.com/"></webview>
  
    test

</body>
</html>
```

---

Another thing that caught my eye was the following two messages while deploying the application from the cca command line;

Permission not recognized by cca: pointerLock (ignoring)
Permission not recognized by cca: webview (ignoring)

Comment: can you provide a full code snippet or further details? What is the thing with the red border? Have you done a css reset?

Comment: Sure thing, added it to the post. The red border is a border to see where the browser is, to make sure it actually loaded haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging I found out that the Webview tag is not supported on mobile devices by Chrome Apps. the Webview tag is a tag created by Cordova and will not work on mobile devices. Therefore you should consider using an iFrame instead.